# Performance criterias of a .net windows application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, performance

I am developing a `window based application` using `.net` framework and `SQL server 2008` as back end. Let me know about the techniques for `improving the performance` of my application.I am using `remote data base connection` .

Comment: So you're developing something that sits between a Db and a User. Your software will be waiting for one of them 99.9% of the time.

Comment: Let Me know the things which i taken care of while developing

Answer (score 4):

You should use a profiler to see where the time is being consumed. There are a few good commerical profilers such as [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) from Red Gate.

Related:

- [What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)
- [Best .NET memory and performance profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49912/best-net-memory-and-performance-profiler)
- [Introducing SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Mark's suggestion is a well known and well accepted way to isolate and debug bottlenecks in the application.  But you might have a hard time determining what to even test, and for a UI application, you might have a hard time determining when you should stop optimizing.

Along those lines, here are some practices to adopt.

The first is to define performance requirements for your application.  Here are some suggestions for doing this for an initial-verison app:

- Determine what is a similar server environment to what you project in production
- Come up with an expected set of scenarios that will be run against the server, including what percentage of each scenario will be run
- Come up with expected peak, average, and worst-case conditions

And here are some suggestions for a subsequent release:

- Measure your existing application's performance against your known data
- Examine the worst outliers, and optimize those first
- Don't accept any reduced performance on any scenario unless it is for a very good reason

The next is to do load testing against your application.

- Deploy your application to a test server environment that matches production
- Automate your various productions loads on your server (both meeting and exceeding production loads)
- Run all your expected scenarios against the server while it is under load, and determine whether it is "responsive enough"
- If you really want to get down and dirty with this, try doing some User Acceptance testing while your server is under load, and try to determine the user's reaction to the responsiveness of the application

Comment: Let Me know the things which i taken care of while developing

Comment: @Nithesh: Is this a comment, or a request for more information?

Comment: @Nithesh: The things I mention are business activities which can occur before and parallel to development, and test activities, which can occur parallel to and after development.  The things that can occur during development are: recognizing opportunities to design in useful optimizations that don't require you to bend over backwards (low level and architectural), unit testing, low-level simple performance measurements based on business requirements (if you break them down to very granular timing budgets), and finding bottlenecks via profiling.