# c# program takes up lots of memory

Tags: c#, .net, memory, httpwebrequest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best .NET memory and performance profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49912/best-net-memory-and-performance-profiler)

My C# program, a web scraper, makes extensive use of async HttpWebRequests, Regex, and HTML agility pack. It's multi threaded using the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem method.

It starts off using around 600,000 K of memory and eventually climbs to over 1,000,000 K.

How can I track what's taking up the most memory and clean it up so it's less resource intensive?

Thanks

Comment: @Adam, you are off by a factor of 1000, though the usage of KB instead of MB is pretty non-standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a memory profiler - they can help to analyse such problems, for example:

- http://memprofiler.com/ (commercial, **managed PLUS unmanaged integrated in one profiler**!)
- http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/ (commercial)
- [CLR Profiler from MS](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273) (free)

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to use a *profiler*.  I've had great success with using the [Redgate ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/), which is not free.  There may be other good choices out there.