# How to find the performance bottleneck in C# desktop application?

Tags: c#, profiling

We have developed a Windows desktop application which is loaded in the server. This application is generally launched from the client by accessing the server. The server will be located in different cities and the client will access this from different cities. For the past few weeks the application has started performing slowly. For example, after clicking a menu to launch an exe, it takes around 30 seconds to launch the exe (the exe resides in the server).

The application does not have any major database activities and most of the activities are page processing which happens in the client machine. I have also checked the windows task manager and there is no major memory utilization by any application or CPU utilization while running this application.

It would be helpful if you suggest me some steps to identify the root cause of this problem along with some profiling tools which can be used in this case please.

Comment: So the server is not in Lan network, your application connects to server with internet connection?. Are the clients using vpn?

Comment: Many versions of Visual Studio ship with a performance profiler that will allow you to sample the application and determine which method is taking the longest. If you have a suitable version, then Analyze -> Launch Performance Wizard will give you these tools.

Comment: I would use the built-in profiler Visual Studio has. It allows you to measure how long a method takes and how many times it's called. For memory profiling, I'ved used CLR Profiler which allows you to see how much memory your application is taking, which objects are being created by which methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2474118/23771

Answer (score 2):

You need a performance profiler which can pinpoint exactly how much time each function (or line) in your program takes.

There are several free and commercial products. I have used [Red Gate Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) and it comes in really handy for such things.

Dedicated topic about the best performance profiler:
[Best .NET memory and performance profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49912/best-net-memory-and-performance-profiler)