# There is a way to know how long each function running in C # in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am looking for information about runtime of function,
like "Include actual execution plan" in SqlServer,
to know how much time took every function execution,
there is any way?
I am work in ASP.NET c# application vs 2003.
Thanks.

Comment: What you are looking for is called a profiler, and there is no such tool included in Visual Studio. There are third-party options, though.

Comment: Here's a couple of commercial profilers you should consider: http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/  https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

Comment: @erikkallen Higher Visual Studio SKUs do actually have profilers ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx )

Answer (score 1):

You can use profiler such as

1. [ants-performance-profiler](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)
2. [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)

See this question: [Best .NET memory and performance profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49912/best-net-memory-and-performance-profiler)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the c# Stopwatch to track how long things are taking: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx

If this is production code and you are worried about the performance, it would probably be worth while to add it's performance to your logging/diagnostics structure, so that it can be monitored in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Check with speed trace and appsight. They are pretty detailed in profiling and recording data.